# Fetch data into modal popup using ajax in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, modal-dialog, backend

I am trying to fetch data from my database into a modal popup and make it dynamic... I'm also a bit confused on how to make the modal id unique for each data on the table... the "button" details pops up the modal.

[This is my Table the buttons pops up a modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Cf6.png)

This is my controller

```
public function show($upi)
{   
    $Patient = Patients::where('upi', '=', $upi)->first();
    return Response::json($Patient);
}
```

> This is my Route

```
Route::get('show-details/{upi}', [BssDashboardController::class, 'show'])->name('details.show');
```

> This is my Ajax script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').on('click', '#show-details', function (){
            var patientURL = $(this).data('url');
            $.get('show-details/' + patientURL', function (d) {

                $('#diagnosisModal').modal('show');
                $('#date').text(data.date);
                $('#age').text(data.age);
                $('#gender').text(data.gender);
                $('#plan').text(data.plan);
                $('#authcode').text(data.authcode);
                $('#findings').text(data.findings);
                $('#compliants').text(data.compliants);
                $('#investigation').text(data.investigation);
            });
        })
    });
  </script>
```

> This is my Button

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="show-details" data-url="{{ $item->upi }}">
                                                <button class="btn-primary px-3 py-1">Details</button>
                                               </a>
```

> This is my modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="diagnosisModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                <div class="col-8 pt-3">
                                                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row"><label><b>Name:</b></label><div class="fw-600" id="name"></div></div>
                                                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row"><label><b>DOB:</b></label><div class="fw-600" id="date">16-03-1990</div></div>
                                                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row"><label><b>Age:</b></label><div class="fw-600" id="age">31 Years</div></div>
                                                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row"><label><b>Sex:</b></label><div class="fw-600" id="gender">Female</div></div>
                                                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row"><label><b>Plan:</b></label><div class="fw-600" id="plan">Equity</div></div>
                                                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row"><label><b>Authcode:</b></label><div class="fw-600" id="authcode">-</div></div>
                                                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row"><label><b>Findings:</b></label><div class="fw-600" id="findings">Pregnant</div></div>
                                                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row"><label><b>Complaints:</b></label><div class="fw-600" id="compliants">ANC</div></div>
                                                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row"><label><b>Investigations:</b></label><div class="fw-600" id="investigation">ANC</div></div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-4">
                                                                    <div class="pt-4" style="width: 5rem;height: 4rem;"><img class="w-100" src="{{ asset('img/drake.jpg') }}" id="image" alt=""></div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal" style="background-color:#ff3030;border-radius:.7rem">Close</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic content in Bootstrap modal and dynamic data in Ajax \[Laravel\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42333434/dynamic-content-in-bootstrap-modal-and-dynamic-data-in-ajax-laravel)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery ID selector works only for the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114622/jquery-id-selector-works-only-for-the-first-element)